# QgsRasterFileWriter.writeRaster() is crashing python program

Tags: pyqgis, ndvi

I am doing NDVI analysis on a farm image. After NDVI, I need to convert the image into singleband pseudocolor image using following Python code.

```py
def calculate():

    file_name =  CUR_DIR + "\sampleodm.tif"
    out_file = CUR_DIR + "\sample_output.tif"
    out_file_ndvi = CUR_DIR + "\out_ndvi.tif"
    try:

        file_info = QFileInfo(file_name)
        rasterName = file_info.baseName()
        raster = QgsRasterLayer(file_name, rasterName)

        if not raster.isValid(): print 'Invalid raster'

        ir = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        r = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()

        print ir, r

        ir.raster = raster
        r.raster = raster

        ir.bandNumber = 4
        r.bandNumber = 3

        ir.ref = rasterName + "@4"
        r.ref = rasterName + "@3"

        references = (ir.ref, r.ref, ir.ref, r.ref)
        exp = "1.0 * (%s - %s) / (%s + %s)" % references
        print exp
        print 'here2'

        output = out_file

        e = raster.extent()
        w = raster.width()
        h = raster.height()
        entries = [ir, r]

        ndvi = QgsRasterCalculator(exp, output, "GTiff", e, w, h, entries)

        ndvi_res = ndvi.processCalculation()
        print ndvi_res

        file_info_out = QFileInfo(output)
        rasterName_out = file_info_out.baseName()
        lyr = QgsRasterLayer(output, rasterName_out)
        if lyr.isValid(): print 'valid raster'

        min = 0.0341278
        max = 0.56844
        range = max-min

        algorithm = QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum
        limits = QgsRaster.ContrastEnhancementMinMax
        lyr.setContrastEnhancement(algorithm, limits)


        i = []
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor(0,0,0,0), 'NODATA'))
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.0341278, QColor(120,69,25,255), 'Lowest Biomass'))
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.168, QColor(255,178,74,255), 'Lower Biomass'))
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.244, QColor(255,237,166,255), 'Low Biomass'))
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.301, QColor(173,232,94,255), 'Moderate Biomass'))
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.435, QColor(135,181,64,255), 'High Biomass'))
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.494, QColor(3,156,0,255), 'Higher Biomass'))
        i.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.56844, QColor(1,100,0,255), 'Highest Biomass'))

        c = QgsColorRampShader()
        c.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
        c.setColorRampItemList(i)

        s = QgsRasterShader()
        s.setRasterShaderFunction(c)
        print lyr.rasterType()
        ps = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(lyr.dataProvider(), lyr.rasterType(), s)
        lyr.setRenderer(ps)

        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)

        extent = lyr.extent()
        width, height = lyr.width(), lyr.height()
        print width, height
        renderer = lyr.renderer()
        print renderer.type()
        provider = lyr.dataProvider()
        crs = lyr.crs()     

        pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
        pipe.set(provider.clone())        
        pipe.set(renderer.clone())

        file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(out_file_ndvi)
        print file_writer
        print 'write'
        # upto here everything is working fine and program is generating black and white image.
        error = file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, provider.extent(), crs)
        # print error
        print 'Completed NDVI analysis!'


    except Exception as e:
        print 'Exception: ', e
```

Consider every module is imported in program.
line `error = file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, provider.extent(), crs)` is causing `Python.exe has stopped` error.

I tried this program on QGIS Desktop application's python console and it is saving the singleband pseudocolor image perfectly.

How do I rectify the error?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding [QgsApplication](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsApplication.html) at the beginning of the code when using Qgis

```
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplicationsetPrefixPath.setPrefixPath("{path to qgis}/qgis", True)
qgs.initQgis()
```

Also, Deleting the layer after writing the program is important to improve memory usage.

```
del lyr
```

Then at the end of the program, add:

```
qgs.exitQgis() # Should only run once per program.
```

Finally, If you are using Qgis 3.8 or higher then  `file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, provider.extent(), crs)` is deprecated and You should use `file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, provider.extent(), crs, transformContext)` [Here is more info about it](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsRasterFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsRasterFileWriter.writeRaster).

Lastly, I would suggest taking a look on this discussed topics that may help to solve your problem:

[Using exitQgis() in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250933/using-exitqgis-in-pyqgis)
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35354